# Wildcard filtering for Defects

Tags: rally

I was curious to know. Is wildcard filtering available / supported by Rally? For example, if I wanted to search for all of my defects in all planned delivery versions from 1.2.1-1.2.9 (effectively 1.2.x), is there a way for me to implement such functionality?

Thanks. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wild card per se but in many cases "contains" operator can effectively return an equivalent result. For example, let's say we have 4 defects with TargetBuild values ranging from 1.0 to 1.2. This query `(TargetBuild contains "1.")` will return all those defects:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?query=(TargetBuild contains "1.")&pagesize=200&fetch=TargetBuild
```

[image]